# Antialised Circle with texture mapping

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

i have a question about a circle which has a texture mapping. My code works well but i have not antialised edges so it is not smooth and looks not good. I have read now about 3 hours and found some solutions but i don't know how can i implement them in my code. There were two solutions which sounds pretty good.

First was a blurry texture which should bind instead of a non blurry to have smooth edges.

Second add color vertices on the edges with opacity to have smooth edges. My currently draw function looks like this:

```
CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

[self.shaderProgram use];

ccGLBindTexture2D( _texture.name );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

ccGLBlendFunc( _blendFunc.src, _blendFunc.dst);

ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords );

// Send the texture coordinates to OpenGL
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _textCoords);

// Send the polygon coordinates to OpenGL
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _triangleFanPos);

// Draw it
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, _numOfSegements+2);
```

I am currently using cococs2d version 3. I asked a similar question and found only the solution of enable the multisampling on cocos2d but this break my fps to 30.

So maybe there is someone how can help me.

Comment: you need to write a shader to do that sort of thing on a per-sprite basis, otherwise multisampling is one alternative or a cheap shot where you draw the same circle 2-3 times but slightly larger and/or rotated and with transparency

Comment: Ok you mean i should use the shader to blur the texture? Or is there an possiblity to use a shader for the antialising. By the way  LearnCocos2D have you some time to write in chat?